# Utilizing Firebase in my Android App, the Data is not Entering Firestore and Recycler View is not updating when I upload something new

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I have been working on this project for a while now. I have a few errors that need to be fixed.

First of all, the one document in my posts collection on Firestore is showing up just fine the way I want it on the Home Page screen. However, when I go to upload a new post to the app, it returns to the home screen with nothing showing. I also see nothing being added to my Firestore collection of posts when I upload a new photo. It is, however, being added to my Firebase storage.

My posts collection's document have 3 fields: 1)GlobalUserId (the user's id) 2)Index (the one in my sole document right now is at 0) 3)MediaURL (the app references this to grab the media and display it in the app, it is a link to the media in Firebase storage.)

I will share a few code to somehow get some help as to what is wrong:

This code is PostActivity. It is the landing page of where a user can upload a photo. It then stores the data and once a successful upload is made, it reroutes you to the main page.

```
public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
        private static final int PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST = 2;

        private Button chooseFileButton;
        private Button submitButton;
        private TextView uploadTextView;
        private ProgressBar progressBar;

        private Uri selectedFileUri;
        private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
        private FirebaseFirestore firestore;
        private FirebaseStorage storage;
        private PostAdapter postAdapter;
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

           //Initialize Firebase Auth, Firestore, and Storage
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

            // Initialize UI components
            chooseFileButton = findViewById(R.id.chooseFileButton);
            submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
            uploadTextView = findViewById(R.id.uploadTextView);
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.postProgressBar);

            chooseFileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openFileChooser();
                }
            });

            submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        submitPost();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            });

            //Initialize UI component
            bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);

            bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.home_navigation) {

                    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(PostActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(homeIntent);

                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.profile_navigation){
                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(PostActivity.this, ProfilePageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(profileIntent);
                }
                else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.post_navigation){
                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(PostActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
                    startActivity(profileIntent);
                }
                return true;
            });
        }

        // Open the file chooser for selecting media
        private void openFileChooser() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/* video/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }

        // Handle result from file chooser
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                selectedFileUri = data.getData();
                uploadTextView.setText(R.string.file_selected + selectedFileUri.getLastPathSegment());
            }
        }

        // Logic to submit the post
        private void submitPost() throws IOException {
            if (selectedFileUri == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Check file type
            String fileType = getContentResolver().getType(selectedFileUri);
            if (!isValidFileType(fileType)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid file type. Please select an image, gif, or video.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Check video duration if it's a video
            if (fileType.startsWith("video")) {
                int videoDuration = getVideoDuration(selectedFileUri);
                if (videoDuration > 30) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Video duration should be 30 seconds or less.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Show progress bar
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Upload the file to Firebase Storage
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference().child("uploads/" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            storageRef.putFile(selectedFileUri)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            // Hide progress bar
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // File uploaded successfully, get download URL
                                storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUri) {
                                        // Add post data to Firestore
                                        addPostToFirestore(downloadUri.toString());
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Upload failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        private int getIndexForNewPost() {
            // Get a reference to the "posts" collection
            CollectionReference postsCollection = firestore.collection("posts");

            // Use a query to get the count of documents in the "posts" collection
            Task<QuerySnapshot> task = postsCollection.get();
            try {
                // Block on the result of the query to get the document count
                QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = Tasks.await(task);
                int documentCount = querySnapshot.size();

                // The count will be the index for the new post
                return documentCount;

            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                // Handle exceptions (e.g., log or show an error message)
                e.printStackTrace();
                return -1; // Indicates an error, handle it appropriately in your code
            }
        }
        // Add post data to Firestore
        private void addPostToFirestore(String downloadUrl) {
            String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            int index = getIndexForNewPost();

            Map<String, Object> postDoc = new HashMap<>();
            postDoc.put("GlobalUserID", uid);
            postDoc.put("MediaURL", downloadUrl);
            postDoc.put("Index", index);

            firestore.collection("users").document(uid).collection("posts").add(postDoc).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            //Update postReferences in user's document
                            updatePostReferences(uid, documentReference.getId());
                            //Call EventChangeListener here to update user data and reflect new post
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Firestore error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });


            firestore.collection("posts")
                    .add(postDoc)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Post submitted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish(); // Close the activity after successful submission
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Firestore error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }


    //Update postReferences in user's document
        private void updatePostReferences(String uid, String postId) {
            firestore.collection("users").document(uid)
                    .update("postReferences", FieldValue.arrayUnion(postId))
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Firestore error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        // Check if the file type is valid (image, gif, or video)
        private boolean isValidFileType(String fileType) {
            return fileType != null && (fileType.startsWith("image") || fileType.startsWith("video"));
        }

        // Get video duration in seconds
        private int getVideoDuration(Uri videoUri) throws IOException {
            MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            try {
                retriever.setDataSource(this, videoUri);
                String durationString = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                long duration = Long.parseLong(durationString);
                return (int) (duration / 1000); // Convert duration to seconds
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            } finally {
                retriever.release(); // Release the MediaMetadataRetriever
            }
        }


}
```

This code is HomeActivity, the main page, where there's a recycler view that shows all the uploads by all the users in a vertical fashion.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<User> userArrayList;
    private ArrayList<Post> postArrayList;
    private PostAdapter adapter;

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore firestore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Initialize Firebase Auth and Firestore
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        // Initialize RecyclerView
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        userArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        postArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new PostAdapter(HomeActivity.this, userArrayList, postArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set up bottom navigation item selected listener
        //Initialize UI component
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.home_navigation) {

                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);

            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.profile_navigation) {
                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfilePageActivity.class);
                startActivity(profileIntent);
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.post_navigation) {
                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
                startActivity(profileIntent);
            }
            return true;
        });
        EventChangeListener();
    }

    private void EventChangeListener() {
        firestore.collection("users").addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e("Firestore error", error.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            userArrayList.clear(); // Clear the list before adding new data
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {
                userArrayList.add(document.toObject(User.class));
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify adapter of the data change
        });

        firestore.collection("posts").orderBy("Index", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e("Firestore error", error.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            postArrayList.clear(); // Clear the list before adding new data
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {
                postArrayList.add(document.toObject(Post.class));
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify adapter of the data change
        });
    }
}
```

I have more code I could show, please ask if you think the problem is elsewhere. I've tried so many times to fix it, but I can't seem to get to the problem. Thank you for your help, I so greatly appreciate it. Again, the problem is that when I upload a photo it doesn't get stored to Firestore nor does it show up on the home page.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).